# From Windows Phone 7.1 to Windows Phone 8.0

Tags: windows-phone

I just copied .cs code to new Windows Phone 8.0 app. There is no error code or something.

All the images on the application I did set in .cs  not in .xaml.

When I debugg the profject there are no images.  Whole images are in construcor. And all are in Canvas. E.G

```
       Image bankImage = new Image()
                {
                    Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/PhoneApp2;component/images/Menu/cash.png", UriKind.Relative)),
                    Height = 80,
                    Width = 250
                };
 Canvas.SetTop(bankImage, 140);
            Canvas.SetLeft(bankImage, 170);
MyCanvas.Children.Add(bankImage);
```

What is the reason that my app has no images on WP8 and on WP7 there is?

Comment: Is the "Build Action" on the image file properties in VS is set to "Resource"?

Answer (score 1):

Solved

Image property Build Action has to be "Content". If there is contect I had to get source like

```
ImageSource = (ImageSource)new BitmapImage(new Uri("/images/AmericanPoker/Bottom.png", UriKind.Relative))
```

No need to use App;component

Answer (score 0):

Don't copy .cs files to new WP8 project.
Just open old WP7 project in newer version of Visual Studio (2012 or 2013) - and it will become WP8 project.

Comment: When I upload this .csproj its sign (incompatibile)